# Inserting a part of a match with a regular expression into a replacement text

Tags: java, regex

I have some text:

`String s = "The Moon is an astronomical body.it is the fifth-largest natural satellite in the Solar System. the Moon is second-densest satellite among those whose densities are known."`

And I want to uppercase every character which is after dot or after dot+space, using replaseAll method.

```
s = s.replaceAll("((?<=\\.|\\.\\s)\\p{Lower})","$1".toUpperCase());
```

Everything is ok, except of `toUpperCase()`. It doesnt do anything. Why? And how can I make it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Note: Using your same pattern (you can improve your pattern)

```
import java.util.regex.*;
```

...

```
StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer( "The Moon is an astronomical body.it is the fifth-largest natural satellite in the Solar System. the Moon is second-densest satellite among those whose densities are known." );
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "(?<=\\.|\\.\\s)\\p{Lower}" );
Matcher m = p.matcher( str );

while (m.find()) {
    str.setCharAt(m.end()-1, Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(m.end()-1)) );
}

System.out.print(str);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is much better).